# Delete specific files from folder, inside a war file using ZipArchive class

Tags: java, powershell, war

My goal is to get some files from the WAR, make changes, delete older files from WAR and then move the edited files to WAR.

At the moment I can find, edit, remove and move files from an WAR file using the ZipArchive class. But the problem I am facing is that I can not remove files from specific folders inside the WAR, just by name.

Given the WAR structure I have: 
~/war
~/war/client/lib/file.jar
~/war/server/lib/file.jar

Until I reached this point I have been using the following function to remove files:

```
function Remove-FilesFromZip {
    param(
        [string]$ZipFile,
        [string]$FileName
    )

    try {
        
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression')
        $Retorno
        $stream = New-Object IO.FileStream($ZipFile, [IO.FileMode]::Open)
        $mode = [IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update
        $zip = New-Object IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream, $mode)
        Write-Host "$zip $mode $stream $Retorno" 

    ($zip.Entries | Where-Object { $FileName -contains $_.Name }) | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }

        Write-Host "$FileName excluido de $ZipFile" 
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Erro ao excluir $FileName de $ZipFile" 

        $zip.Dispose()
        $stream.Close()
        $stream.Dispose()
    }

    $zip.Dispose()
    $stream.Close()
    $stream.Dispose()

}
```

Since the files I was deleting only came up once on my WAR, it was not a problem, but if I try something like this:

```
Remove-FilesFromZip "C:/pathToWar/warFile.war" "file.jar"
```

Both files are deleted from the war.

And if I try to use the path like so:

```
Remove-FilesFromZip "C:/pathToWar/warFile.war" "/server/lib/file.jar"
```

Nothing happens.

How can I edit my function so I can describe the path to the file I would like to delete ?

Also, for context I have another function that I use after this one, that I can move files to the war and to the desired folder, but when I move without deleting the file with same name, I got duplicate files inside and this is not desirable.

This is the function:

```
function Move-FileToZip {
    param(
        $ZipFileName,
        $FileNameInZip,
        $NewFileToAdd
    )
    try {
        # Write-LogWIthTime "-------------- Move-FileToZip --------------"

        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem') | Out-Null
        $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($ZIPFileName, "Update")

        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem') | Out-Null
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($zip, $NewFileToAdd, $FileNameInZip, "Optimal") | Out-Null
        $zip.Dispose()

        Write-Host "Adicionado com sucesso $NewFileToAdd as $FileNameInZip para $ZIPFileName "
    }
    catch {
        $zip.Dispose()
        Write-Host "Falha ao adicionar $NewFileToAdd para $ZIPFileName . Detalhes : $_" 
    }
}
```

That I use as:

```
Move-FileToZip "C:/pathToWar/warFile.war" "/server/lib/file.jar" "C:/updatedFiles/server/lib/file.jar"
```

The ideal scenario for me would be to simply update the file when I use the Move-FileToZip function, but just getting the Remove-FilesFromZip to work as I intend it would be great!

Comment: Since WAR is just a zip archive, why not extract it, do whatever, and rezip it? Maybe the Java folks have better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your `Remove-FilesFromZip` function is that you are filtering the Zip entries by using the `Name` property and so you're not able to distinguish between the files with the same name but in different directories.

```
 $zip.Entries | Where-Object { $FileName -contains $_.Name }
```

If you filter instead using the `FullName` property then you should be able to target the specific file by using it's full name within the zip file:

```
 $zip.Entries | Where-Object { $FileName -eq $_.FullName }
```

With that change you should be able to do something like the following, assuming that `client` is a top level directory within the zip file:

```
Remove-FilesFromZip "C:/pathToWar/warFile.war" "client/lib/file.jar"
```

Comment: It worked using the property `FullName`. 
As a newbie on powershell, didn't thought on the properties of the `$_ `.

Thank you @don-cruickshank for your time.